Browser and vscode freeze occasionally when using multiple desktops
I had noticed that Brave Browser and Visual Studio Code will occasionally freeze.
I had been using Windows 11 multiple desktops.
I closed all the extra desktops, leaving only 1 desktop.
The freezing went away for weeks.
I then opened a 2nd desktop.
The issue came back within a day.
chrome based apps?
Since the issue affects Brave and Visual Studio Code, both of which use a chrome engine, perhaps this only affects chrome-based apps?
Update: chrome
I loaded a site in chrome and left it open.
When I noticed that brave froze, chrome was also frozen, but vscode was not.
Update: edge
I loaded TradingView in Edge.
When brave froze, Edge and chrome also froze. Firefox didn't freeze. vscode was not frozen.
This also points to chrome based apps.
Update: memory usage
The system has 64GB of RAM. One of the times that the issue occurred, only 36GB of RAM was being used, according to Task Manager. It seems memory isn't the issue.



Try reducing Chrome's high resource usage with suggestions from The Windows Club and Make Use Of. In an effort to make the browser engine ever-faster, Google has increased RAM (and pagefile / swapfile) use.

If RAM is a constraint, the OS may need to use more virtual memory, which, even using SSD, is far slower than RAM. Experiment with adjusting the size of VM. Depending on the situation, decreasing, as well as increasing the size of VM can improve speed. BTW, I set initial and maximum sizes the same to help avoid fragmentation.


Also, compare Chrome with other browsers, e.g., Firefox or its derivatives, to see if it definitely is at fault for the freezes.

I've updated the question to include a screenshot of the memory usage at the time that the issue occurs. It doesn't seem like memory is the issue.

Look for drive I/O as a limiting resource, too.
